# How do I use array for php strtok?

Tags: php, string

In my code example above, I split a string with strtok. But another zone of the page;

```
// echo $tok[1]; ...... echo $tok[9];
```

I want to pull data like ... But I couldn't do it. How can I do it?

edit: Actually, what I want to do is this: I want to be able to pull all the data on a column in the database and print them one by one.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE sublink IS NOT null", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $query->rowCount() )
{
    foreach( $query as $row ){
        $deger = $row['sublink'];

        $tok = strtok($deger, ".");

        while ($tok !== false) {
            echo "$tok<br />";
            $tok = strtok(".php");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to "pull" data like what? What do you mean by you couldn't do it?

Comment: The `token` argument is not a substring, it's a set of characters that are all delimiters.

Comment: Push `$tok` onto an array and use it in the other part of the page.

Comment: Hello. Actually, what I want to do is this: I want to be able to pull all the data on a column in the database and print them one by one.

Comment: What does that have to do with `strtok`? Just echo `$deger` each time through the loop.

Comment: actually no need for it. You are right. but I had to try every way as I didn't know how to do it. Whatever I did, I couldn't separate the show.